# PyQt Printing raw PDF

Tags: python, pdf, printing, pyqt4

Assuming I have a *test.pdf* file in the current directory, I would like to send this raw file to a printer using the *PyQt gui Printer*.

The following Python3 code prints the PDF source code! I don't want Qt to build the PDF for me, but just send it to the printer with a gui dialog box.

This should work on any OS, (no `lp` command) ...assuming that the printer device understands PDF natively.

```
import sys, PyQt4.QtCore, PyQt4.QtGui

def pdf():
    pdf = open('test.pdf', encoding='utf-8').read() # ascii PDF here
    doc = PyQt4.QtGui.QTextDocument(pdf)
    printer = PyQt4.QtGui.QPrinter()
    dialog = PyQt4.QtGui.QPrintDialog(printer)
    if dialog.exec_() == True:
        doc.print_(printer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget()
    but = PyQt4.QtGui.QPushButton('Print', w)
    but.clicked.connect(pdf)  
    PyQt4.QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w).addWidget(but)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**:

The original answer below only relates to PyQt4. For PyQt5, see this answer:

- [How to use QPrinter and QPrintPreviewDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8193920/984421)

---

*Original answer*:

There is built in [support](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qprinter.html#OutputFormat-enum) for *writing* a document in PDF format, but not for *reading* one.

To read PDF documents, you will have to use a third-party library, or use an external tool to convert the pdf to another format (such as text, or html) first.

See [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Handling_PDF) for an overview on handling PDF documents.

Comment: Too bad! I cannot belief there is not a solution without changing the original PDF document.